# Wrong values in Global stiffness matrix FEM

Tags: python, numpy, math, matrix

so i'm using FEM in my master's thesis and was asked to make a script that assembles "local" stiffness matrix (each element has 4 nodes, and each node has only 1 degree of freedom). Below is an example of the "local" and "global" systems for my analysis:

[Local and global systems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zu7H.png)

So, assuming that the local stiffness matrix is the same for both elements, and is given by:

[Local stiffness matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oYaW.png)

I made a script that assembles the stiffness matrix of the 2 elements in this example:

```
def stiff_mat_assemble(mesh, stiff_mat_ele): #stiff_mat_ele is the "local stiffness matrix"
'''
mesh - tuple of the mesh created
mesh[0] is a n*2 array (n - total number of nodes), and stores the coordinates of each node
mesh[1] is a 4*4 array, stores the nodes of each element
'''
global_stiff_mat = np.zeros((mesh[0].shape[0],mesh[0].shape[0])) #Gives a matrix n*n, n being the number of nodes in each direction

for element in mesh[1]: #cycles through all elements
    for i in element: #i global
        for j in element: #j global
           i_index = get_index_int(element, i) #gives the local index of "i"
           j_index = get_index_int(element, j) #gives the local index of "j"
           global_stiff_mat[i,j] += stiff_mat_ele[i_index, j_index] 

return global_stiff_mat
```

And the result is this global stiffness matrix:

[Global stiffness matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scgbX.png)

The problem is that i'm getting very strange values for the inverse of this matrix:

[Global stiffness matrix Inverse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QhSH.png)

And, by what i've read, the inverse of this matrix, should be equal to the original matrix: (K^-1)^-1 = K. And this is why i think i made a mistake in that script, but i can't figure out what is the error... Would be very appreciated if someone could help me out as i'm still a begginer! 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your global has the right pattern, with nodes 2 and 3 showing the overlap of the 2 elements.  I've solved FEMs with boundary conditions and forcing, but never looked at the plain inverse of the stiffness matrix.  Your inverse looks like the matrix is singular or nearly so.  Without boundary conditions that might be typical.  What does the theory say?

Comment: i see.. i'll ask my mentor about that and see if it's a normal occurence. Thanks!